# .htaccess how to substitute urls

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I substitute URLs of a web application in a sub folder as installed on root.

e.g. need to map
    example.com/index.php
to
    example.com/new/index.php

I do not want redirection but url rewrite to exempt folder name.

Help me to learn and define rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following rule to rewrite any request that’s URL path (without path prefix) does not start with `new/`:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^new/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new/$1
```

This will also work in .htaccess files other than in the document root directory.

But as you want to use this rule in the .htaccess file in the document root directory, you could also use *REQUEST_URI*:

```
RewriteRule !^new/ new%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first line matches all requests not matching `/new/...` and prefixes it with a new before it.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ new/$1
```

Request: `http://example.com/index.php`
Maps to: `[document root]/new/index.php`